# jQuery Form Validator - How do I dynamically change validation parameters in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am using jQuery Form Validator (http://formvalidator.net/)

I would like to know how to dynamically change the validation parameters using client side script (Javascript/Jquery).

Specifically I am trying to change

```
data-validation-length="0-500"
```

to

```
data-validation-length="1-500"
```

in a textarea.

EDIT:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7B8sq/)

---Jade

Comment: Change the data attribute value

Comment: I have added a demo of the issue above - The problem that I am seeing is that the custom data attribute is changing, but the validation is not resetting, it is still using the old values for validation!

Comment: Use `attr` instead of `data`. I guess the JQuery validator is taking values using `attr`. `http://jsfiddle.net/7B8sq/1/

I have added my answer using both

Comment: @ShijuKBabu Thank-you so very much, you are a champion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to add/edit the data-attirbutes.

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="textareaid" data-validation-length="0-500"></textarea>
```

**JQUERY Using attr()** - [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LGAJ5/)

```
$("#textareaid").attr("data-validation-length","1-500");
```

**JQUERY Using data()** - [JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LGAJ5/2/)

```
var txtareaid=$("#textareaid");
txtareaid.data("validation-length","1-500");
var txtval=txtareaid.data("validation-length");
console.log(txtval);
txtareaid.val(txtval);
```

**UPDATE 1**

As per your demo, I guess JQuery validator is taking attribute using `attr` instead of `data`. That's why it is not able to get the updated value.

[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7B8sq/1/)

Answer (score 1):

use JQuery [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/QzEj8/)**

try with

```
$("div").data("validation-length","1-500");
```

I suggest to use `.data()` because its pretty [much faster](http://jsperf.com/jquery-is-data-faster-than-attr-data) than `.attr()`

Comment: The problem that I am seeing is that the custom data attribute is changing, but the validation is not resetting, it is still using the old values for validation!